# Maven getting the same install name and deploy name as the build name

Tags: java, maven

I have project with a parent pom that has

```
<modules>
  <module>a</module>
  <module>b</module>
  <module>original_ear</module>
  <module>original_web</module>
</modules>
```

I tried using `<finalName>changed_Web</finalName>` in webmodule POM
and `<finalName>changed_ear</finalName>` in EAR module POM.
I am getting getting desired `xy_Web.war` and `xy_ear.ear` in `target` but the install and deploy, I am still getting `original_ear-version.ear` and `original_web-version.ear`.

How can I get the same name to deploy and install as well?

Comment: You cannot do it. Period.

Comment: why don't you change the module name? the and whats the issue with the artifact name at all? The context the application runs in does not need to match the war or ear filename at all?

Answer (score 0):

Maven will not do that.  You will have to rename the files you make based on the file type.  You might want to make a bat file for that or add it to the bat file you are using.

Comment: It's not that Maven won't do that. Having a script won't help you. It's that Maven repositories will simply not accept a file with a custom name, and will always rename it according to the standard naming, based on its coordinates.